# I have got a string, and want this to be repeated 'l' times in java

Tags: java, string, integer

From a loop, I will get the value of `l`.
imagine this value was 3.
I therefore want a string to be repeated 3 times. This means that I want to do the string * l, however this is not possible since one is a string and one is an int. I literally need string to be repeated `l` times.

e.g. If the string entered was `"cat"` and `l` had an outcome of 3, I would get the output of `"catcatcat"`. 
thankyou

here is my coding:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Task2 { 
    public static void main (String[] args){
        Scanner kb=new Scanner(System.in); 


        System.out.println("Please give me a message:"); 

        String strMessage = ("^[?=.*!@#$%^&*]+$");
        strMessage=kb.nextLine();



        System.out.println("Thank you! Now please give me a keyword:"); 

        String strKeyword=kb.nextLine();    

        String strAlphabet= "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

        double Intlength2 = strKeyword.length();
        double Intlength = strMessage.length(); 
        double Intlength3 = Intlength/Intlength2;
        Intlength3 = Intlength/Intlength2;

        for (int l=0; l<Intlength3; l++){
```

Comment: Does this compile: `String strMessage = ("^[?=.*!@#$%^&*]+$");`?

Comment: Your code doesn't seem to match your description

Comment: not at the moment, but i will fix that part later once i have solved my real issue

Comment: I don't understand why you declare `strMessage` like that and never use its value. You also initialize `Intlength3` and then re-assign the _exact same_ value to it. What's with that? You also don't use `strAlphabet` in this code snippet. Is this part of a larger project?

Comment: @DegenSharew Yes it does. There's just no need for the brackets.

Comment: this is part of a larger programme, i have not shown the whole java

Answer (score 6):

1. make a `StringBuilder` and append the string `l` times

   ```
   StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
   for (int i = 0; i < l; ++i) {
       sb.append(string);
   }

   String result = sb.toString();
   ```
2. If you use Java 8 there is also this "simple" one liner :

   ```
   String result = IntStream.range(0, l).mapToObj(i -> string).collect(Collectors.joining());
   ```
3. Solution using Guava libraries:

   ```
   String result = Strings.repeat(string, l);
   ```
4. Solution using Apache Commons libraries :

   ```
   String result = StringUtils.repeat(string, l);
   ```

As a side note, `l` is not a good variable name as it looks like the number one.

Answer (score 0):

Here are 2 more Java 8 one-liners:

```
String result = Stream.generate(() -> "cat").limit(3).collect(Collectors.joining());
String result = Collections.nCopies(3, "cat").stream().collect(Collectors.joining());
```